# Adding numbered markers via Google spreadsheets to mapbox

Tags: mapbox

Is it possible to add and sync points on a map + numbered markers via mapbox? For example if I wanted to have 20 map points in San Francisco with markers labeled 1-20 and then another 20 map points in the East Bay with markers labeled 1-20 would that be possible to add and sync via a google doc? or would I need to manually enter those points?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this REST API: https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/static/#markers

You could write a script that pulls info from the Google spreadsheet and adds markers using that API.